# Calculating points from number of days worked in a week/month by each employee

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to calculate the average points for employees for a period of a week (or calendar month if possible) from a range of records. I have a table: daily_schedule which has records like this

[image]

I have tried the query:

```
SELECT WEEK(date)
,employeeid
,AVG(points)
FROM `daily_schedule`
GROUP BY WEEK(date), employeeid
```

But that is calculating the average on jobs rather than the date per employee
The result I want to achieve is

[image]

Is there any way to achieve the average by week and/or calendar month?

Thank you in advance.#

Comment: please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question and make a [mre] in text form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WEEK(date)` function will give you the number of week in the year from that date. And if you want to achieve what you've mentioned here, you can simply `group by WEEK(date) and then employeeid`. You can execute a CTE in this purpose. Then select the aggregated grouped values from CTE and AVG from `points/days` collected from cte.

So you can execute:

```
with cte as (select employeeid, sum(points) as points, count(distinct date_val) as days, WEEK(DATE_VAL) as week_no
    from daily_schedule ds group by WEEK(date_val), employeeid)
select week_no, employeeid, points, days, points/days as avg from cte;
```

From the week no, you can identify which week of the year this is.
This will give you the expected output.

Output of this query is:

| week_no | employeeid | points | days | avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | 113877 | 4.5 | 2 | 2.25 |
| 26 | 122396 | 4.2 | 2 | 2.1 |
| 26 | 124514 | 3.7 | 1 | 3.7 |
| 27 | 113877 | 1.8 | 1 | 1.8 |
| 27 | 122396 | 1.2 | 1 | 1.2 |
| 27 | 124514 | 1.6 | 1 | 1.6 |

Comment: Hi devReddit, that was the result I was after. Very helpful. Thanks a lot.